# How to show only selected item information in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, layout, angular-material

In my project I have this Help/FAQ Dialog. I'm trying make
only selected information to display but not sure how to do that so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

For example,

when the user selected Item 1 from expansion panel, The right columns will display only Item 1 information and hide the others.

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="dialog-container">
    <div class="container-inside-dialog">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column left" style="background-color:pink">
                <mat-nav-list>
                    <mat-expansion-panel>
                      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        Header 1
                      </mat-expansion-panel-header>            
                  <a mat-list-item routerLink>Item 1</a>
                  <a mat-list-item routerLink>Item 2</a>
                  <a mat-list-item routerLink>Item 3</a>
                    </mat-expansion-panel>
                  </mat-nav-list>

                  <mat-nav-list>
                    <mat-expansion-panel>
                      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        Header 2
                      </mat-expansion-panel-header>     
                  <a mat-list-item routerLink>Item 4</a>
                  <a mat-list-item routerLink>Item 5</a>
                    </mat-expansion-panel>
                  </mat-nav-list>
            </div>
            <div class="column right" style="background-color:grey">
              <!-- Show this only when Item 1 is selected -->
                <h2>Item 1</h2>
                <p>Some text for Item 1..</p>
                <p>more text.......</p>

              <!-- Show this only when Item 2 is selected -->
                <h2>Item 2</h2>
                <p>Some text for Item 2..</p>

              <!-- Show this only when Item 3 is selected -->
                <h2>Item 3</h2>
                <p>Some text for Item 3..</p>

              <!-- Show this only when Item 4 is selected -->
                <h2>Item 4</h2>
                <p>Some text for Item 4..</p>

              <!-- Show this only when Item 5 is selected -->                
                <h2>Item 5</h2>
                <p>Some text for Item 5..</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is what it look like right now]

This is my stackblitz project https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-bn9uwv

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in steps

1-detect click on each item u want to be clicked

2-identify each click separately

3-store each click index or number

4-using that number show only desired item

here is code

**Component**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic expansion panel
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'expansion-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'expansion-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['expansion-overview-example.css'],
})
export class ExpansionOverviewExample {
  panelOpenState = false;

  clickedIndex = -1;

  clicked(index:number){
    this.clickedIndex = index;
    console.log(index);
  }

}


/**  Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

**Template**

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="dialog-container">
    <div class="container-inside-dialog">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column left" style="background-color:pink">
                <mat-nav-list>
                    <mat-expansion-panel>
                      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        Header 1
                      </mat-expansion-panel-header>            
                  <a mat-list-item routerLink (click)="clicked(1)">Item 1</a>
                  <a mat-list-item routerLink (click)="clicked(2)">Item 2</a>
                  <a mat-list-item routerLink (click)="clicked(3)" >Item 3</a>
                    </mat-expansion-panel>
                  </mat-nav-list>

                  <mat-nav-list>
                    <mat-expansion-panel>
                      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        Header 2
                      </mat-expansion-panel-header>     
                  <a mat-list-item routerLink (click)="clicked(4)" >Item 4</a>
                  <a mat-list-item routerLink (click)="clicked(5)">Item 5</a>
                    </mat-expansion-panel>
                  </mat-nav-list>
            </div>
            <div class="column right" style="background-color:grey">
              <!-- Show this only when Item 1 is selected -->
                <ng-container *ngIf= "clickedIndex == -1 ||  clickedIndex ==1">
                <h2>Item 1</h2>
                <p>Some text for Item 1..</p>
                <p>more text.......</p>
                </ng-container>
              <!-- Show this only when Item 2 is selected -->
                <ng-container *ngIf= "clickedIndex == -1 ||  clickedIndex ==2">
                <h2>Item 2</h2>
                <p>Some text for Item 2..</p>
                <p>more text.......</p>
                </ng-container>
              <!-- Show this only when Item 1 is selected -->
                <ng-container *ngIf= "clickedIndex == -1 ||  clickedIndex ==3">
                <h2>Item 3</h2>
                <p>Some text for Item 3..</p>
                <p>more text.......</p>
                </ng-container>
              <!-- Show this only when Item 1 is selected -->
                <ng-container *ngIf= "clickedIndex == -1 ||  clickedIndex ==4">
                <h2>Item 4</h2>
                <p>Some text for Item 4..</p>
                <p>more text.......</p>
                </ng-container>
              <!-- Show this only when Item 1 is selected -->                
                <ng-container *ngIf= "clickedIndex == -1 ||  clickedIndex ==5">
                <h2>Item 5</h2>
                <p>Some text for Item 5..</p>
                <p>more text.......</p>
                </ng-container>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center start">
        <span style="flex-grow: 1;"></span>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" mat-dialog-close [style.marginRight.px]="20"
            matTooltip="Close Help">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi hanan, thank you so much for providing me this and I really appreciate it. One quick question, do you know how I can display just Item 1 information (kinda like default) when the dialog is open everytime because right now  just like the image above every items information is displaying when the dialog is open and they only start to hide when I select from  the expansion panels.

Comment: make clickedIndex = 1;

Comment: Thank you so much!